# How to recreate Haptic Feedback Vibration when you long press on app icon

Tags: swift, xcode, vibration, haptic-feedback

How can I recreate the exact vibration that happens when you hold down on an app icon like this in swift?[image]

The same vibration can be felt when you swipe on a message on Facebook messenger to reply to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `UIFeedbackGenerator` for this, for example:

`UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.success)`

or

`UISelectionFeedbackGenerator().selectionChanged()`

Comment: This is the one: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.init(style: .heavy).impactOccurred()